# MDX Select measures between two values

Tags: mdx

I have a fact table which stores for each record an init_year and end_year as integers, which refer to the year range in which the record is valid.

In which way I can design a MDX query to select my measures (count) for each year, in order to have a trend of my measures over year?

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this should be done in MDX.

This sort of thing is usually calculated in the fact tables (linked to a dimension table of all available years), and a new measure is created. No calculation would be done in MDX; you'd just display the new measure.

Having said that, I've just Googled "MDX count start end date" and found [www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2013/04/mdx-between-start-date-and-end-date](http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2013/04/mdx-between-start-date-and-end-date/) which suggests you use the LINKMEMBER function. Their example code was...

```
    AGGREGATE( 
      {NULL:LINKMEMBER([DATE].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER
                 ,[START DATE].[Calendar])}
    * {LINKMEMBER([DATE].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER
                , [END DATE].[Calendar]):NULL}
    , [Measures].[Project COUNT])
```

...or...

```
AGGREGATE({NULL:[DATE].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER}
        , [Measures].[Project COUNT])
```

...but it needs careful reading!